# Prism architecture considerations for ClickOnce deployed applications

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce, prism

I'm creating a new application using Prism and ClickOnce, but while testing ClickOnce's hash checking for delta-only updates I noticed that I would need to make some architecture changes to take full advantage of ClickOnce updates.

To be clear, I am deploying to machines with poor internet connections and I really want to publish small, quick updates with minimal bandwidth.  Ideally, only modules that have been modified would be sent over the wire.

First, I noticed that the client application project's hash (the one that makes the .exe) was always changed no matter what, and always re-downloaded.  This lead me to remove Shell.xaml, ShellViewModel.cs, and some ResourceDictionaries and move them into a new ShellModule. This leaves AggregateModuleCatalog, Bootstrapper, App.xaml, and App.cs; each file is fairy small so this is fine.

Second, I noticed that ClickOnce's programmatic updating could go into a module, so I have that in a AutoUpdateModule.

Finally, my last concern is the Infrastructure project.  Each module directly references Infrastructure, and if Infrastructure is modified all modules get new hash values.  I believe this means that even if I add a line to an enum inside Infrastructure the whole app will be re-downloaded.

Is there an elegant solution to this issue? And if you've deployed Prism applications using ClickOnce what are some other architectural modifications that have helped or improved your deployment?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Prism, however, there is no way within ClickOnce to apply partial updates for standard applications.

I had a similar problem (I think) with a Windows app project that I was working on about 5 years ago.  Specifically, my users often had spotty data connections (connecting over some times poor cellular data connections) and I needed to be sure that my updates were as small as possible.

Even though I could prevent the full application from being re-downloaded after each update, I did find that there were numerous, third-party dlls that never changed.  So, I created a separate installer that placed those modules in the Windows GAC and they were installed only once, when the prerequisites were installed.  This cut my application size down from 25MB to 2MB-- quite an improvement.

I'm not sure if this applies to your circumstance, but it might help.